# Clang equivalent of of GCC's march=native flags output

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, clang, cross-compiling

I am trying to find clang equivalent to gcc's `gcc -v -march=native -E - </dev/null` command.

What this command does is that, I run it on my target system where I want my final program to run. Fetch the flags that gcc would use to optimize it according to the target system. And then build it on my system with those flags after that.

What the clang equivalent (i.e. `clang -v -march=native -E - </dev/null`) does is almost the same but the case is that the final output cannot be directly copied to use during compilation. Some flags printed by this command donot work with clang command line compilation. I would be grateful if someone who faced a similar situation could help on this.

A sample output of clang flags is :

```
"/usr/bin/clang-13" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu goldmont -target-feature +sse2 -target-feature -tsxldtrk -target-feature +cx16 -target-feature +sahf -target-feature -tbm -target-feature -avx512ifma -target-feature +sha -target-feature +gfni -target-feature -fma4 -target-feature -vpclmulqdq -target-feature +prfchw -target-feature +bmi2 -target-feature -cldemote -target-feature +fsgsbase -target-feature +ptwrite -target-feature -amx-tile -target-feature -uintr -target-feature +popcnt -target-feature +widekl -target-feature +aes -target-feature -avx512bitalg -target-feature +movdiri -target-feature -xsaves -target-feature -avx512er -target-feature -avxvnni -target-feature -avx512vnni -target-feature -amx-bf16 -target-feature -avx512vpopcntdq -target-feature +pconfig -target-feature +clwb -target-feature -avx512f -target-feature -xsavec -target-feature -clzero -target-feature +pku -target-feature +mmx -target-feature -lwp -target-feature +rdpid -target-feature -xop -target-feature +rdseed -target-feature +waitpkg -target-feature +kl -target-feature +movdir64b -target-feature -sse4a -target-feature -avx512bw -target-feature +clflushopt -target-feature -xsave -target-feature -avx512vbmi2 -target-feature +64bit -target-feature -avx512vl -target-feature +serialize -target-feature +hreset -target-feature +invpcid -target-feature -avx512cd -target-feature -avx -target-feature -vaes -target-feature -avx512bf16 -target-feature +cx8 -target-feature -fma -target-feature -rtm -target-feature +bmi -target-feature -enqcmd -target-feature +rdrnd -target-feature -mwaitx -target-feature +sse4.1 -target-feature +sse4.2 -target-feature -avx2 -target-feature +fxsr -target-feature -wbnoinvd -target-feature +sse -target-feature +lzcnt -target-feature +pclmul -target-feature -prefetchwt1 -target-feature -f16c -target-feature +ssse3 -target-feature -sgx -target-feature +shstk -target-feature +cmov -target-feature -avx512vbmi -target-feature -amx-int8 -target-feature +movbe -target-feature -avx512vp2intersect -target-feature -xsaveopt -target-feature -avx512dq -target-feature +adx -target-feature -avx512pf -target-feature +sse3 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/trading/users/hardik/clang_examples -resource-dir /usr/lib/clang/13.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/trading/users/hardik/clang_examples -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 2 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o - -x c -
```

The following errors arise when I try to copy these:

```
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-main-file-name’; did you mean ‘--print-file-name’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mrelocation-model’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-pic-level’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-pic-is-pie’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mframe-pointer=all’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mconstructor-aliases’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-munwind-tables’; did you mean ‘-funwind-tables’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-cpu’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-tsxldtrk’; did you mean ‘-mtsxldtrk’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-tbm’; did you mean ‘-mtbm’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512ifma’; did you mean ‘-mavx512ifma’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-fma4’; did you mean ‘-mfma4’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-vpclmulqdq’; did you mean ‘-mvpclmulqdq’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-cldemote’; did you mean ‘-mcldemote’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-amx-tile’; did you mean ‘-mamx-tile’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512bitalg’; did you mean ‘-mavx512bitalg’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512er’; did you mean ‘-mavx512er’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avxvnni’; did you mean ‘-mavxvnni’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512vnni’; did you mean ‘-mavx512vnni’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-amx-bf16’; did you mean ‘-mamx-bf16’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512vpopcntdq’; did you mean ‘-mavx512vpopcntdq’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512f’; did you mean ‘-mavx512f’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-clzero’; did you mean ‘-mclzero’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-sse4a’; did you mean ‘-msse4a’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512bw’; did you mean ‘-mavx512bw’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512vbmi2’; did you mean ‘-mavx512vbmi2’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512vl’; did you mean ‘-mavx512vl’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512cd’; did you mean ‘-mavx512cd’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx’; did you mean ‘-mavx’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-vaes’; did you mean ‘-maes’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512bf16’; did you mean ‘-mavx512bf16’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-fma’; did you mean ‘-mfma’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-rtm’; did you mean ‘-mrtm’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mwaitx’; did you mean ‘-mmwaitx’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx2’; did you mean ‘-mavx2’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-wbnoinvd’; did you mean ‘-mwbnoinvd’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-prefetchwt1’; did you mean ‘-mprefetchwt1’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-f16c’; did you mean ‘-mf16c’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-sgx’; did you mean ‘-msgx’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512vbmi’; did you mean ‘-mavx512vbmi’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-amx-int8’; did you mean ‘-mamx-int8’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512vp2intersect’; did you mean ‘-mavx512vp2intersect’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512dq’; did you mean ‘-mavx512dq’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-avx512pf’; did you mean ‘-mavx512pf’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-target-feature’; did you mean ‘-Wtarget-lifetime’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/trading’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-resource-dir’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-internal-isystem’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-internal-isystem’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-internal-isystem’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-internal-externc-isystem’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-internal-externc-isystem’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/trading’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-ferror-limit’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-stack-protector’; did you mean ‘-Wstack-protector’?
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-fgnuc-version=4.2.1’
cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-faddrsig’
```

Comment: Yes, I am building on a different machine.

Comment: OP, please add to your question: the command line generated and which flags are actually causing a problem.

Comment: @PaulSanders Added. As I said they cannot be directly copied. I might need to do some intelligent selection but some options aren't even supported.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `-march` with whatever the target machines architecture is?

Comment: You only need to extract the argument of `-target-cpu goldmont` and pass it to `-march` on the build system, I think. I don't know whether `-target-cpu` and `-march` are using exactly the same arguments though and I also don't know whether there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: @user17732522, I don't think that just passing goldmont will capture all the information about the target system. We need to capture 'all' the possible optimzations specific to the target.

Comment: @HardikAggarwal `-march=native` has exactly the same effect as `-march=goldmont` if the CPU is a Goldmont. That's how the `native` option works.

Comment: And maybe submit a bug report: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues (although I suspect they won't prioritise this)

Comment: @user17732522 I tried with `clang++ -march=native -v <target>` and `clang++ -march=goldmont -v <target>` on a machine where target-cpu was goldmont. The output was different, so I guess they work differently.

Comment: The only difference I see is that `-march=native` includes a list of cpu features which look redundant with the `-target-cpu` option to me.

Comment: Looking at the LLVM sources, the Clang driver detects the individual CPU features via `cpuid` and adds them to the `cc1` invocation when you use `-march=native`, but the CPU features should already be included in the architecture description enabled via the `-target-cpu` option. I am not sure whether there are any cases where these two mismatch. In any case, the output clang is giving are not options to the driver, but to `cc1`. You need to translate them if you want to pass them as driver options.